# How to downgrade Node version with n

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, n

I installed the latest node version 18.9.0 with brew. The I installed n with `npm n`. I can't switch the active version from 18.9.0 to 17.4.0 using n. I am not keen on using nvm, is there a way to do it with n?

I installed the latest version (18.9.0) first and then installed n globally and then now am trying to change the version with n, but I cannot seem to change the active version to a the lower one installed with n.

After installing n globally, I `sudo n 17.4.0` but it does not change the active version.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace statements are showing that you have two copies of node installed. The one installed by `n` (to `/usr/local/bin/node`) is later in your `PATH`. The "active" version was installed by homebrew.

You could uninstall the homebrew version, or modify your PATH.

(If you run `n doctor` this problem will be detected and explained.)

Comment: Thank you, this is the right diagnosis. Simply brew uninstall node and the terminal will run the one in the n folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have said using

```
$ n 17.4.0
```

is not working for you, maybe you could try using

```
$ n
```

And then pick the version you want using the arrow keys? That seems to work for me.

Comment: Nope.. doesn't work. Did you install the latest version prior to installing n? I installed the latest version first and then am now trying to change the active version with n.

Answer (score -1):

first - install it globally :

```
$ npm install -g n
```

then - run this code:

```
$ n 17.4.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Nodejs.org has previous releases versions in their distribution directory. Find the node version you need and install it.

https://nodejs.org/dist/